# how to set a readonly property value in Json.net in the JsonConverter

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.net 4.5. I am using JsonConverter to convert the data from one version to another version.

Version 1

```
    public class AV1
    {
        public string PNr { get; set; } // "x253yN-69Uj"
    }
```

Version 2

```
    public class AV2
    {
        public string FirstNr { get; private set; } // "x253yN"
        public string LastNr { get; private set; } // "69Uj"

        public void SetFirstAndLastNr(string a, string b, string c)
        {
            //Logic to set the values of FirstNr and LastNr
        }
    }
```

In the derived JsonConverter, I am creating the instance of `AV2` class. But since properties are readonly properties now, how should i set the value of these properties? Does Json.net offers any methods to do the same? Or do i have to use reflection?

Comment: JSON.NET has a lot of nice features which the out-of-the-box serializers don't. It's even been adopted by Microsoft itself as the default serializer for one of their products (ASP.NET Web API).

Comment: What do the parameters `a`, `b` and `c` mean on the method `SetFirstAndLastNr` in the class AV2?

Comment: @carlosfigueira - The parameter a, b, c are some query parameter to query a repository and based on the query result calculate a unique number which is now split into this FirstNr and LastNr. there were other examples such as logical path and document name etc. But i do not think we need to bother about this method at all

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deserialize read-only property , maybe try this

```
public class AV2
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly string _firstNr;
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly string _lastNr;
    public string FirstNr => _firstNr// "x253yN"
    public string LastNr => _lastNr// "69Uj"


}
```

Answer (score -4):

As you said you have hundreds different classes which needs to be converted, `JsonDeserializer` might not be the best choice.

It's not a bad idea to look at other solution like **AutoMapper**: http://automapper.org/ , https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

If you spend an hour or two and look at the sample codes, you will find it so powerful and flexible to convert (map) different object to each other.